# I'm getting notifications I shouldn't be getting

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, ios-app

I got some notifications in the iOS app that don't exist in my inbox (and shouldn't):

[image]

These don't have anything to do with me, as far as I can tell - and like I said, they aren't in my inbox on the web.

Comment: umm... what happened to your diamond??

Comment: Oh, crap!  I lost it somewhere!

...I've left SE to pursue another opportunity to start a business of my own.  As great as SE has been, sometimes you gotta do what you gotta do ;-)

Comment: haha, great for you and thanks for everything you fixed!! If you'll arrange a goodbye party count me in! (psst, time to update your About Me too ;))

Comment: Ah, yes: thanks for the reminder on the about me

Comment: I think you need to buy the domain first, @Ben. ;) Anyway, good luck on your adventures!

Comment: @hichris123 I got `epicraft.co`.  some things can't be helped :-).  If we find that not having the .com is a major issue, there's always `.ninja`

Comment: @BenCollins http://epicraft.co/ looks parked to me currently. Or is that your new business? ;P

Comment: @hichris123 Yep, that's it.  Still sorting through naming issues and other administrative muckety-muck before we actually put anything up on the web

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That was fun.

Basically: When we are changing a user's account type (in your case from `Employee` to `Registered`) we queue an action to run on every site to do that. Part of that action is "While we're running, also run this on the child-meta for this site so that they're in sync", for some reason when we did it the first time that part failed silently. This means your account was left in a state where you were a moderator on lots of child-metas, but not on any main sites.

The notifications weren't showing up in your global inbox because we have a stopgap for showing them there (there's a method called `IsInInbox()` which takes a notification type) -- we don't have the same check for push notifications however, so the disconnect happened there which was super confusing.

You also weren't getting notifications about *all* metas you had an account on getting new questions because when you visited one of the sites you have an account on the meta-user was immediately getting refreshed so you lost moderatorship upon page load.

Anyway, I have no clue what caused this, the code looks right and we didn't get any errors from it which is super odd. I literally hit the button for changing your account type again and everything is fixed now.

<3, sorry it took days to get to this.

Comment: "sorry it took days" - thousands of bugs wait for long years to be fixed, so really no need to be sorry! :-)